# Any hint/idea of solving this recurrence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Recurrence relation here:
$$ L(n) = \sum_{i=2}^n L(i-2)L(n-i),\,\, L(0)=1 $$

[Original immugur image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZAvy.png)

Comment: What is $L(1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

You may wish to consider the Catalan Numbers, which satisfy the following recurrence relation. $$ C_{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}C_i\,C_{n-i}\quad\text{for }n\ge 0$$
As provided [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Properties). Now what relation does the Catalan Numbers has to your
recurrence relation?

Comment: Helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I will as soon as I can.Thanks!